# ObjectDisposed Exception on second XPS export

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application that is used to open files in a document viewer for the purposes of 1: not allowing users to alter the files, and 2: to track the files that are opened and how long they are open for.

That said, I have the files they select (either Word Docs or Excel Workbooks) converted into XPS files and placed in a DocumentViewer in a WPF project.

The first time a document is opened, it works as intended. However, as soon as a second file is attempted to be opened, I get a

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Package object was closed and disposed, so cannot carry out operations on this object or any stream opened on a part of this package.

I have been searching for hours now and have no idea what is going on.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class DocumentViewerFileGenerator
     {


        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a docuemnt, of the IDocumentPaginatorSource type to be used by the document viewer in the
        /// view. By looking at the extension type, decides on which interop to use.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Path of the file that is to be converted</param>
        /// <param name="extension">Extension of the file. Makes it easier for the if's</param>
        /// <returns>A converted IDocumentPaginatorSource version of the file to be viewed.</returns>
        public XpsDocument GenerateDocumentForViewer(string filePath, string extension)
        {

            string tempOutputPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\temp.xps";
            ClearOldTemp(tempOutputPath);

            XpsDocument xpsDocument;
            if (extension == ".doc" || extension == ".docx")
            {
               ConvertWordToXps(filePath, tempOutputPath);
            }

            if (extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx")
            {
               ConvertExcelToXps(filePath, tempOutputPath);
            }

            xpsDocument = MakeFixedDocument(tempOutputPath);

            return xpsDocument;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Just clears out the old temp path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tempOutputPath"></param>
        private void ClearOldTemp(string tempOutputPath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(tempOutputPath))
            {
                File.Delete(tempOutputPath);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the file selected, through Word, into an XPS for conversion purposes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">The file to be converted. Full path needed.</param>
        private void ConvertWordToXps(string filePath, string tempOutputPath)
        {
            Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
            word.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
            word.Visible = false;
            Word.Document document = word.Documents.Open(filePath);
            document.SaveAs2(tempOutputPath, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
            document.Close();
            word.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the file selected, through Excel, into an XPS for conversion purposes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">The file to be converted. Full path needed.</param>
        private void ConvertExcelToXps(string filename, string tempOutputPath)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
            workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypeXPS, tempOutputPath);
            workbook.Close();
            excel.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            excel = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tempOutputPath"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private XpsDocument MakeFixedDocument(string tempOutputPath)
        {
            return new XpsDocument(tempOutputPath, FileAccess.Read);
        }


    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel for displaying the document:

```
public FileViewerViewModel(string fileName, string exentsion)
        {
            DocumentViewerFileGenerator generator = new DocumentViewerFileGenerator();

            try
            {
                FileToDisplay = generator.GenerateDocumentForViewer(fileName, exentsion);
                FileToShow = FileToDisplay.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                IsMainEnabled.Instance.IsWindowVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }

            catch (Exception log)
            {
                //Error handeling
            }

              /// <summary>
        /// The file that is to be shown on the view model.
        /// </summary>
        private IDocumentPaginatorSource fileToShow;
        public IDocumentPaginatorSource FileToShow
        {
            get { return fileToShow; }
            set {
                if (value == fileToShow)
                    {  return; }
                fileToShow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                }
        }

        private XpsDocument FileToDisplay
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Our good, generic PropertyChanged handler. Glorious.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

         private void ClosingWindow()
        {
            if (AutoLogoutTimer.Instance.IsLogOff != true)
            {
                UnlockXPSFile(FileToDisplay);
                IsMainEnabled.Instance.IsWindowVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void UnlockXPSFile(XpsDocument fileToUnlock)
        {
            Package xpsPackage = PackageStore.GetPackage(fileToUnlock.Uri);
            xpsPackage.Close();
        }
 }
```

As I said before, the first time this runs through, it works fine.

However, the second time it goes to make a new xps file at this line:

```
 private XpsDocument MakeFixedDocument(string tempOutputPath)
 {
      return new XpsDocument(tempOutputPath, FileAccess.Read);
 }
```

The exception gets thrown.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what calls `UnlockXPSFile` which seems to be the only place in your code which disposes xps package.

Comment: @Evk the only time it's called is in the `ClosingWindow()` method. The whole viewmodel, view, and the xps object itself is re instantiated after a new file is selected. That's why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well after doing quite of a bit of head scratching, more Googling and banging my face against the keyboard, it dawned upon me what I was missing...

```
private void UnlockXPSFile(XpsDocument fileToUnlock)
{
    Package xpsPackage = PackageStore.GetPackage(fileToUnlock.Uri);
    xpsPackage.Close();
    PackageStore.RemovePackage(fileToUnlock.Uri); //This line right here
}
```

While I was closing the package, I wasn't actually removing it from the package store. So, the application was looking for the same package store to store the new XPS folder in, but since it was closed and dumped, it had no where to go.